# Subsetting data.frame upon two constraints

Tags: r, subset

Say I want to subset using 2 constraints.
1, being the values in the first column be identical 
2, and at the same time, the values in the second column be the same

For example, I have a data frame

```
a <- rep(1:5)
b <- c(1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2)
data <- data.frame(a,b)
```

say `a` is the pair identification number and `b` represents the gender

now we want to subset to create a dataset where we have a matched pair ID and gender.

Would one create a loop using the `while` command or use the `duplicated`

the expected results should return a subset of data that is highlighted here in green

[image]

Comment: This is a nice question with reproducible example and desired output, but your explaining skills need some improvement.

Comment: Apologies. how would you reword ?

Comment: "I'm trying to extract only the rows when `b` has only one unique value per `a`"? Something like that probably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
data[with(data, !!ave(b, a, FUN=function(x) 
                      length(unique(x))==1)),]
```

Or

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
      group_by(a) %>%
      filter(n_distinct(b)==1)
```

Or

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[,.(b=b[length(unique(b))==1]) , a]
```

Or another `data.table` solution provided by @David Arenburg

```
setDT(data)[, if (length(unique(b)) == 1) .SD, a]
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg, Thanks, is it faster than the subset (out of curiosity)